# how to specify s3 config for spectrify python package?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

how to specify this `s3_config` object for python spectrify package ?

```py
from spectrify.export import RedshiftDataExporter
RedshiftDataExporter(sa_engine, s3_config).export_to_csv('my_table')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the spectrify package is not great, but a quick read through [the code](https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify/blob/master/spectrify/utils/s3.py) and the examples will show you that s3_config can be an instance of S3Config or SimpleS3Config, both defined by the spectrify package. Here's an [example](https://github.com/hellonarrativ/spectrify/blob/master/examples/weekly_partitions.py):

```
csv_path_template = 's3://my-bucket/my-table/csv/{start.year}/{start.month:02d}/{start.day:02d}'
spectrum_path_template = 's3://my-bucket/my-table/spectrum/partition_key={start}'

# Construct a S3Config object with the source CSV folder and
# destination Spectrum/Parquet folder on S3.
csv_path = csv_path_template.format(start=start_date)
spectrum_path = spectrum_path_template.format(start=start_date)
s3_config = SimpleS3Config(csv_path, spectrum_path)
```